# my program isn't displaying the right average,it is giving me only zeros in decimal(New to Programming)

Tags: c

here is the code as written in visual studio

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void main() 
    {
      int n,i,num,s;
      float av;
    printf("How Many numbers?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    s=0;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){

        printf("enter number #%d  : ",i);
        scanf("%d", &num);

        s=s+num;    

    }

    av=s/n;
        printf("The Average is %f",av);
    getchar();
    }
```

i really don't know why it isnt displaying the right average :/

Comment: Use a debugger or print things as you go and see which line goes differently from what you expect.

Comment: This looks like a C program, not a C++ program. C & C++ are different languages. BTW, compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g.  `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Always test result item count from `scanf`; and terminate your `printf` format string with `\n` or else learn about `fflush`

Comment: yeah i just noticed that i tagged it with c++ sorry,i'll edit it

Comment: void main() is not a valid main function declaration.  suggest: int main( void).  then end the function with 'return (0 );'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here: `av=s/n;` you are storing the result of an integer division into a float, there will be some data loss. A simple solution: use typecasting->

`av=(float)s/n;`

or

`av=s/(float)n;`

Another alternative: make either `s` or `n` a float.

Answer (score 1):

*`av=s/n;`* Lookup [*"integer division"*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5Dinteger%20division). You probably want to use `av=(float)s/n;`

Division of two integer values doesn't automatically convert to a `float` value, unless you use a cast.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer,i really totally missed that float course